# How to use ltxtable

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, ltxtable

I created a table in the appendix of my thesis with the tabularx-package and afterwards I realized it is way too long and does not jump over to the next page. I tried to use ltxtable to make it jump over to the next page and now spended a whole afternoon but could not make it work... I installed this in my Master-file:

```
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

And this is the code for my table:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\TabelleA1.tex}
\begin{longtable}{ccccccccccccccc}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{table}} % Setting table number output to letters 
\setcounter{table}{0}
\caption[This is my table]{\textit{In reality it has 74 rows}}
\toprule
ID& Age & Sex & Group & WST & IQ & Code &    AQ  & ADOS Kommunikation & ADOS Sozial & ADOS Total & ADI-R Sozial & ADI-R Kommunikation & ADI-R Verhalten & ADI-R Beginn\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
1&29&w&ASS&21&85&AS& 40  &5&7&12    &   14&10&2&3 \\
2&26&m&ASS&27&93&FA& --- &5&9&14&   23&16&5&3\\
3&31&m&ASS&31&101&FA& 29 &4&5&9&        30&16&11&4\\
4&25&w&ASS&34&110&AS&35&3&8&    11& 21& 13& 6&  2\\
5&35&m&ASS&33&107&AS&43&2&5&    7&  17& 4&  4&and many more lines\\
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\vspace{2mm}
{\raggedright \footnotesize{\textit{Note.} Abbr = Explanation.}\par}
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{\jobname-Tabelle1.tex}
```

The error message i get:

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> <argument> \TabelleA
> 1.tex
> l.4 \begin{filecontents}{\TabelleA1.tex}
> ```

Is the filecontents package not installed? If I delete the lines relating to file content, latex is running "Process is started" but never stops and never creates a pdf...
Can I not use `\toprule`, `\midrule` etc. in this environment?
Or is the problem the 15 columns?
I am desperate, would be great if you could help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe?

Comment: Also, are you bound to use the `ltxtable` package or could you switch to an alternative such as `xltabular`?

Comment: In addition to the stray `>` caracters in your code (See `>\usepackage{caption} `)  there is a `\\ ` missing after your caption command. Also, as you only used `c` type columns (and no `X` type columns that yould be typical for `tabularx`)  why do you need an environment that combines the features of `longtable` and `tabularx`?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{table}} ` should also be used outside of the `longtable` environment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion using a simple `longtable` in combination with the `threeparttablex` package for the table notes. I have also moved some repeated information from the column headers into a common header and introduced some abbreviations. In order to make the table fit to the textwidth (of a standard `report` with the `geometry` package loaded). I have also reduced the font size to `\small` and changed the horizontal white space between adjacent columns (`tabcolsep`). Lastly, I have used the `textfont=it` option of the `caption` package instead of manually setting the text of the caption to use italics.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[textfont=it]{caption} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[flushleft, para, referable]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{table}} 
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\note Abbr = Explanation.
\end{TableNotes}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{ccccccccccccccc}
\caption[This is my table]{In reality it has 74 rows}\\
\toprule
& & & & & & & &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{ADOS} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{ADI-R}\\
\cmidrule(r){9-11} \cmidrule(l){12-15}
ID& Age & Sex & Group & WST & IQ & Code &    AQ  &  Kommun. &  Sozial &  Total & Sozial &  Kommun. &  Verh. &  Beginn\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes\\
\endlastfoot
1&29&w&ASS&21&85&AS& 40  &5&7&12    &   14&10&2&3 \\
2&26&m&ASS&27&93&FA& --- &5&9&14&   23&16&5&3\\
3&31&m&ASS&31&101&FA& 29 &4&5&9&        30&16&11&4\\
4&25&w&ASS&34&110&AS&35&3&8&    11& 21& 13& 6&  2\\
5&35&m&ASS&33&107&AS&43&2&5&    7&  17& 4&  4& \\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

---

For an improved alignment of the numbers, you could also make use of the `siunitx` package as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[textfont=it]{caption} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[flushleft, para, referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\note Abbr = Explanation.
\end{TableNotes}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{cccccS[table-format=2]ccccS[table-format=2]cS[table-format=2]S[table-format=2]c}
\caption[This is my table]{In reality it has 74 rows}\\
\toprule
& & & & & & & &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{ADOS} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{ADI-R}\\
\cmidrule(r){9-11} \cmidrule(l){12-15}
ID& Age & Sex & Group & WST & {IQ} & Code &    AQ  &  Kommun. &  Sozial &  {Total} & Sozial &  {Kommun.} &  {Verh.} &  Beginn\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes\\
\endlastfoot
1&29&w&ASS&21&85&AS& 40  &5&7&12    &   14&10&2&3 \\
2&26&m&ASS&27&93&FA& --- &5&9&14&   23&16&5&3\\
3&31&m&ASS&31&101&FA& 29 &4&5&9&        30&16&11&4\\
4&25&w&ASS&34&110&AS&35&3&8&    11& 21& 13& 6&  2\\
5&35&m&ASS&33&107&AS&43&2&5&    7&  17& 4&  4& \\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks really cool thank you! I wish I could use it but now I get this message:! LaTeX Error: Command \tnote already defined. What can I do about it?

Comment: @PiaGe: Did you recieve this error message with the MWE from my question or if you add the code into your actual thesis document?

Comment: the second thing

Comment: @PiaGe: Without knowing what other packages you load in your thesis I can unfortunately not help you. Therefore please try to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows me to reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: You mean a MWE of which packages I loaded? I hope this is okay: ```\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{color}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[flushleft, para, referable]{threeparttablex}```

Comment: @PiaGe: If I take the example code from my answer and add the list oc packages from your last comment, I still can't reproduce the error messae you describe. Something else must be causing this. What documentclass do you use?

Comment: \documentclass{scrreprt}

Comment: @PiaGe: This is also not the cause of the error. Please copy the file that you got the above mentioned error message from, comment out a part of it, compile and see if the error remains. If so, continue until you have the smallest possible document that still reproduces the error message. This ist then the before mentioned MWE tht wen can then use to work with.

Comment: @PiaGe If you use `scrreprt` the packages `caption`, `geometry` and `fancyhdr` is unnecessary, because `scrreprt` has internal commands that give similar or better results. In addition, you load `caption` twice. You should load `xcolor` instead of `color`. The problems seems to be that you load a program that define a command called `tnote`, which `threeparttablex` also tries to define.

Comment: @leandriis you were totally right, I googled the error message and found out that it is an error that occurs in combination with ctable. I checked my packages again and there was a \usepackage{ctable} I missed. Sorry for wasting your time and thank you for the great example!

Comment: @PiaGe: Thanks for your feedback. I'm happy to hear that could solve the problem.